# svc doesn't work

Tags: wcf, iis, svc

I have some problem and trying to solve for a few days..

I installed iis 6.0 but I updated it 7.5 express and 7.0. it looks 7.5 version..

so, I published wcf to localhost and set 4501 port. I can see file  when I run iis   `http://localhost:4501/`

but svc file doesnt work. When I click or type  `http://localhost:4501/Products.svc`  it doesnt work and I see a blank website.. nothing..

But If I run svc client in visual studio, asp.net development server works and my svc file works..     (http://localhost:4501/Products.svc) everything is same..

I dont understand why IIS doesnt work well?

I think that 6.0 doesnt support .. I use a proxy and I can connect to my global ip with proxy or my friend opens it.. but still svc file doesnt work..

I think the problem is iis.. but a global side, asp.net development server doesnt work too, but it works on localhost..

I opened all ports, add some new rule to firewall and i closed firewall (modem and computer)

I really become a crazy..

Edit: I try to connect ip with `http://myGlobaLIp:4501`  I can see my files on my localhost but If I try `http://myGlobalIp:4501/Products.svc` I get blank page..

Comment: In the end, I couldn't understand which version of IIS you are using. Have you updated from 6.0 to 7.5?

Comment: firstly I installed 6.0, after I installed 7.5 express and after I installed 7.0. on ISS, I can see version is 7.5

Comment: How, exactly, did you install IIS 7.0 or 7.5 instead of 6.0? IIS 6.0 doesn't work on Windows 2008, and IIS 7.x doesn't work on Windows 2003.

Comment: version is 7.5 :) and I use windows 7 ultimate

Comment: After your installation of IIS 7 or 7.5 did you perform an aspnet_regiis -i? Also in IIS http is on port 80 by default and when you try to access http://localhost:4501/products.svc wont be accessible. You need to configure the port mapping on IIS by right clicking on default website --> edit binding --> select http --> edit --> change the port to 4501 from 80.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue: when you run from Visual Studio it automatically runs a virtual IIS for you, and assigns the ip/port...in this case it's `http://localhost:4501/`.  When you setup the site and run it in IIS, you have to set those values during the website setup.

You need to create a website in IIS, then point to your code (publish it to a location like c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp)
You then need to set which port your webservice should run on.

THEN, go to http://{your ip or machine name}:{port configured in IIS, not the VS virtual IIS port}/Products.svc

Here is a step-by-step walk through from Microsoft to help you deploy a website (or wcf webservice): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f6c26eb7-ad7e-4fe2-9239-9f5aa4ff44ce.aspx

good luck

Comment: thank you for nice answer.. but  problem hasnt solved yet.. whih port I must set? 4501? I looked wcf server gives http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SchoolServiceLibrary/StudentService/mex  and i dont know how can I change 8732 or its fine ?

Comment: No problem.  You can set the port in IIS to anything you desire, 80 is usually used for your main website.  You could try something like :86.  This must be set in IIS when setting up the website/service.  Setting it to 4501 will cause you headaches.  Here is a step-by-step walk through from Microsoft to help you deploy a website (or wcf webservice): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f6c26eb7-ad7e-4fe2-9239-9f5aa4ff44ce.aspx

Comment: I already created.. I realized something. If I wrote endpoint address wrong, I get error from localhost.. but If I write true, then I get blank page. I dont understand it .. its very weird and I think i cant solve it :s